# ng-animate animation direction

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to get some simple ng-animate behavior working, but have hit a wall and can't quite work out what I am doing wrong.

My code contains a angularui ui-view with a class that dictates the direction the UI View should arrive from - either the left hand side or the right hand side of the screen to giev the impression of a sliding panel that either shows or hides data.

You can see what I am after here - pay attention to the direction of the link arrows;

http://plnkr.co/edit/H2eRr5pPNKTDHXFXsyUn

The ui view code is;

`<div ui-view class="{{whichWayToMove}}"></div>`

With a couple of routeChange event listeners to detect when the appropriate CSS should change the direction of where the ui views come from.

I have an feeling the problem is a scoping one, but would appreciate some outside help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had a problem with the `ui-view` sometimes sliding the wrong way.
My problem was that the class was part of the ui-view, but the ui-view gets duplicated to be able to slide one view out and one view in. During this duplication one view got the old class and the other view got the new updated class like this:

```
<div ui-view="" class="slide_from_left_to_right ng-animate ng-enter ng-enter-active">
</div>
<div ui-view="" class="slide_from_right_to_left ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active">
</div>
```

This messes up the animation. Putting the `class="{{whichWayToMove}}"` in the parent `div` prevents this and makes your css more logical.`.slide_from_right_to_left` will be the parent class for the RTL situation under which all animation for both views is present. You can see what I mean at the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLOzvgEAvSIlYy51GpNR?p=preview).

Comment: Applying the direction-class to the parent container of the `ui-view` is exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each time you switch tab it creates a new controller for that tab so you keep registering new listeners for the $stateChangeStart without deregistering the old. This means that when a new listener is registered (to change the whichWayToRemove property) it is eventually being overwritten by the first handler registered.

Take a look at the console logging in the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bn4TDMzl6cyR7NNvrt0H?p=preview) to see what I mean.

A working version can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngt8IgCFd7ewDv39LNYN?p=preview) that listens for the event on the $scope rather than the $rootScope, so that when the controller gets removed, the $scope is removed along with it and so is no longer listening for the $stateChangeStart event

**Update**

To get the animations to occur in the direction of the arrows you just need to change which classes get set when. This has been updated in the [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngt8IgCFd7ewDv39LNYN?p=preview). I have also removed the listening event as the whichWayToMove property will just get set when the controller gets created.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not quite working yet - when tab 2 comes into view it is working correctly, but when the link on tab 2 is clicked on then it doesn't move in the direction of the arrows. What I have been struggling to get working is getting both tabs to move in the same direction, either 1 and 2 move to the left, or 1 and 2 move to the right.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how to get the animations following the arrows. I am not sure what you are looking for when you say you want both tabs to move in the same direction thought. Does that mean you don't want them to follow the arrows? Anyway, you should be able to accomplish what you need at this point

Comment: use `ng-class` instead of `class`